# I have an excel sheet of 85,038 rows, how do I randomly select 10% of these?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There are 5 columns (first name, email, userid, app name) and I want to randomly select 10% of these rows and export it eventually to a CSV while maintaining the column headers i listed above. thanks a million

Comment: Create an array of integers that has 8504 elements of the data type integer.  Then use random to generate random numbers for each position in the array checking to see if the value has already been used. Once complete you have ten percent of the rows randomly. - I dont think it can be done via a formula so what I suggested was VBA based.

Comment: @Sorceri `I dont think it can be done via a formula` I kinda disagree to that. :)

Answer (score 14):

I don't know how random you want this to be but adding a column containing `=RANDBETWEEN(1,85038)` copied down to suit, then sorting that column and selecting the first 8,504 rows should give quite an 'arbitrary' result.

Comment: How I can do this if I want to select random number of rows from data which are not incremental like 1 to 100, they are experiment random data collected. Any advice? Here is the excel file https://www.dropbox.com/s/iqanxh8f4dax5rr/control-to%20delete%20332%20random%20values.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with SQL and the Microsoft Query functionality in Excel (Data ->...-> From Microsoft Query)?

If yes then use this

```
( SELECT "first name, email, userid, app name" )
UNION   
( SELECT TOP 8503 t.[first name] & "," & t.[email] & "," &  t.[userid] & "," & t.[app name] 
FROM [Sheet1$] AS t ORDER BY RND() )
```

Then copy an paste to an empty text file and save as CSV

You can also use my SQL addin for this http://blog.tkacprow.pl/?page_id=130

EDIT 1: I assumed that "Sheet1" is the name of your worksheet

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution for you using *Array Formula*.
Suppose you have data in Column A (in this example I used 100 data only).

[image]

Now in C2, type the following formula: ([Credits to Oscar.](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/07/03/how-to-create-a-random-list-of-unique-numbers-in-excel/))

`=IF(ROW(A1)<=0.1*COUNTA($A$2:$A$101),INDEX($A$2:$A$101, LARGE(MATCH(ROW($A$2:$A$101), ROW($A$2:$A$101))*NOT(COUNTIF($C$1:C1, $A$2:$A$101)), RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS($A$2:$A$101)-ROW(A1)+1))),"")`

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the formula to work. 
Using just <kbd>Enter</kbd> will return #N/A.
Then to get the rest of the values, just drag the formula down.
In this example, I just auto-fill up to C20.

**Note:** Randbetween is volatile. So recalculation happens everytime you change something. If you are to return 8k data, that would be a lot of recalculation. It may take a while.

Comment: @pnuts Yep. That's why I pointed out that in the last line. But the better would still be the manual approach you proposed. And of course, VBA would be best using array manipulation. Not really convinced that this is the way to go, I just posted it since it is close to OP and as you said, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I personally used a handy and useful plugin or lets say add-on specially for the Microsoft Excel 2016 / 64 bit.  It is called Kutools. 
You can freely download and use it via this link:

[Download Link](https://d2d42mpnbqmzj3.cloudfront.net/downloads/KutoolsforExcelSetup.exe)  (for both 32 Bit & 64 Bit)
[Kutools Website](https://www.extendoffice.com/download/kutools-for-excel.html)

After downloading and installing you can select random number of rows from the kutools tab-> Range -> Sort Range Randomly ->Select 
then you can enter the amount of your need to select the rows from and that's it.

[Fig of Kutool tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWR2V.jpg)
[Fig of Select Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xag5i.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think this will help to generate any percentage from a list.

If *Col A* has your list
In *Col B*: **RAND()** and fill down.
In *Col C*:
**IF(ROW()>10%*COUNTA($A$2:$A$37),"",INDEX($A$2:$A$37,RANK.AVG(B2,$B$2:$B$37,0),1))**  and fill down. Only the proportion you want will appear in the list.